# How to avoid Selected Item object in list-view hitting twice?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Selected Item Object is hitting twice. How to Resolve it.I'm Using two listview in stack layout both are referring the same object.

```
<ListView x:Name="listview"ItemsSource="{Binding NewDeviceSessionList}"SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceSession, Mode=TwoWay}">

 private DeviceSession _deviceSession;

 public DeviceSession DeviceSession { 
 get => _deviceSession; 
 set=> SetProperty(ref _deviceSession, value); 
 CallSome();
 }

 private void CallSome()
 {
  if(DeviceSession==null) return;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for format

Comment: Can you use [itemselected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemselected?view=xamarin-forms) to distinguish two listViews? I'm not very clearly about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using below code

```
   public DeviceSession DeviceSession
    {
        get => _deviceSession;
        set
        {
            if (_deviceSession != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _deviceSession, value);
                CallSome();
            }
        }
    }
```